# Is there code generator for Django like Gii?

Tags: django, yii2, code-generation, gii

I use Gii code generator with Yii2 framework for more that 3 years ago.
Now I want to change to Django but I need a similar code generator.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **Telosys** (https://www.telosys.org) a lightweight  code generator that is able to generate any kind of langage (**Python** among others) with any kind of framework (possibly **Django**).
This tool is quite simple, free and Open Source.
It provides a CLI (Command Line Interface) and Eclipse plugin, so it can be used with any IDE

It is usualy used to boostrap a project and to generated all the repetitive code (CRUD, Controllers, unit tests, HTML pages, etc)

Some Python application templates are already available (not for Django but it can serve as an example):

- https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/python-web-mvc-bottle
- https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/python-persistence-sqlalchemy

See also this tutorial: https://www.slideshare.net/lguerin/telosys-tutorial-code-generation-for-a-python-web-application-based-on-bottle-and-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. Django has some great built-in features that makes coding web applications so much easier, but you have to write Python to use it.

But don't be afraid, it's quite easy to learn!

Comment: Can you tell me the great built-in features? So I can learn it. Thanks!